# Angular Datatables REST based per page data with explicit table rendering

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datatables

I have followed the approach "[DataTables: Custom Response Handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25211553/datatables-custom-response-handling)" by Fabrício Matté. However, my requirement is to avoid rendering of table's rows and columns via callback. Instead, would like to traverse the current ajax request returned json data and render explicit html (tr/td) to have more control. Due to this, currently i see data shown twice on my table. At the same time, i understand that callback is rendering the page related buttons: prev, 1,2 next etc and click events which i would like to reuse and wan't to avoid custom implementation.

JS:

```
function notificationsCtrl($scope,$http,$resource, DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnBuilder) {
var vm = this;
vm.notifications = [];
$scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
    .withOption('serverSide', true)
    .withOption('ajax', function(data, callback, settings) {
        // make an ajax request using data.start and data.length
        $http.get('notifications/list?page=' + (((data.start)/10)+1)).success(function(res) {
            // map your server's response to the DataTables format and pass it to
            // DataTables' callback
            callback({
                recordsTotal: 120,
                recordsFiltered: 120,
                data: res
            });
            vm.notifications = res;
        });
    })
    .withDataProp('data') // IMPORTANT¹
    .withOption('processing', true)
    .withPaginationType('full_numbers');

    $scope.dtColumns = [
                        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('notificationId').withTitle('notificationId'),
                        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('createUserId').withTitle('createUserId'),
                        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('Language').withTitle('language')
                      ];
```

}

HTML: sample but actual will require extra processing for some of the td tags

```
<table datatable="" dt-options="dtOptions" dt-columns="dtColumns" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
                <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Id</th>
                            <th>Title</th>
                            <th>Language</th>
                            <th>Last Updated</th>
                            <th>Actions</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr ng-repeat="notification in wynkCMSToolApp.notifications">
                            <td>{{ notification.notificationId }}</td>
                            <td>{{ notification.title }}</td>
                            <td>{{ notification.Language }}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
            </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to render directly in the HTML, consider using the [Angular renderer](http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/angularWayWithOptions). However, such renderer does not support the server side processing.

So I recommend you use the server side processing along with the [columns.render](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) function.

Here an [example](http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/rowSelect) of using the render function.