# Custom filters don't work with ajax.data. Json created by django-datatables-views

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, datatable, datatables

I use `djando-datatables-view` in order to create the json data for `datatables jQuery plugin`.
My data is displayed fine. Sorting works either. I created additional `<input>` to search data only in the second column of my table. When I'm writing something in 'search-input-text' i can see the processing modal but table rows aren't filtered at all.
I can't find any information about how to do custom filters with `ajax.data`. I am a newbie and I've been spending three days to find the solution. Please. help:) My code:

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
        var dataTable = $('#datatabletest').DataTable({
          "processing": true,
          "serverSide": true,
          "ajax":{
      "url" :"http://...tojson",
      "type" : "get",
     error: function(){  // error handling
        $(".datatabletest-error").html("");
        $("#datatabletest").append('<tbody class="datatabletest-error"><tr><th colspan="3">ERROOOOR</th></tr></tbody>');
        $("#datatabletest_processing").css("display","none");

                        }
}           
        });
        $("#datatabletest_filter").css("display","none");
        $('.search-input-text').on( 'keyup', function () {
          var i =$(this).attr('data-column');
          var v =$(this).val();
          dataTable.columns(i).search(v).draw();
        } );
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

See this response over here:
[DataTables: Custom Response Handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25211553/datatables-custom-response-handling/38728497#38728497)

It relates to Tastypie interaction, but the concept for amending the search criteria by passing a function to datatables AJAX option is easily extended to whatever is providing your API.

You might want to add a console.log(data) to your ajax function so you can see exactly whats being submitted.